# Apache .htpasswd not applied to subdirectories

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, wordpress, htpasswd

I have several WordPress staging sites placed in a staging directory.
The staging directory holds a .htaccess and .htpasswd

.htaccess:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted area"
AuthUserFile /var/www/staging/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

.htpasswd

```
username:PdadsaasdMehzdsadwad
```

When I place a file in this directory, the authentication process triggers appropriately, however when I place a WordPress site in the subdirectory, the authentication is not showing.

Example WP site: /var/www/staging/some-wp-site

.htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

WP Site Vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName somewpsite.com
        ServerAlias somewpsite.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/staging/some-wp-site
        <Directory />
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/staging/some-wp-site>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride all
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

my apache.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/staging>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

I suspect I need to modify the vhost to use the authentication, however since I have quite a few sites in that directory I would prefer if there was a globl rul that simply triggers for any files placed in this subdirectory, no matter what another configuration says. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is indeed that you are using `.htaccess` files even though you have access to the main Apache configuration files.

> In general, you should only use .htaccess files when you don't have access to the main server configuration file. There is, for example, a common misconception that user authentication should always be done in .htaccess files, and, in more recent years, another misconception that mod_rewrite directives must go in .htaccess files. This is simply not the case. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html

In this case the unexpected behavior that the  `.htaccess` file in `/var/www/staging` is not applied happens because, as far as I know, Apache will only search for and apply any `.htaccess` files found in the DocumentRoot directory and below. I.e. only `/var/www/staging/some-wp-site` and subdirectories thereof.

I am fairly certain that if you create a directory block in your main httpd.conf to require Authentication on `/var/www/staging` it will also apply to all subdirectories and every virtual host with a `DocumentRoot` in there.

Comment: i changed apache2.conf to below but still no luck...

    `<Directory /var/www/staging>
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "restricted area"
            AuthUserFile /var/www/staging/.htpasswd
            require valid-user
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>`

Comment: Additionally I've noticed that vhost rules override apache.conf rules... so this appears to be the problem. I guess I have no way than modifying the vhost and remove Require all granted

Comment: "Apache will only search for and apply any `.htaccess` files found in the DocumentRoot directory and below" - This is not actually true. Whether `.htaccess` files are applied is dependent on what area of the filesystem the `AllowOverride` directives cover, regardless of the DocumentRoot setting. (It is common to set `AllowOverride All` just on the DocumentRoot, so it might seem that this is the case.) However, the OP is already setting `AllowOverride All` on the `/var/www/staging` directory, so this is not the problem here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `Require all granted` directive in the `<Directory>` container inside your `<VirtualHost>` is overriding the authentication directives in the `.htaccess` file in the *parent* directory. This should be removed and instead allow access to the `/var/www` directory (if you have sites outside of the "staging" area) and restrict access to the `/var/www/staging` subdirectory, as you are doing, although it would be preferable to do this in the server config, not `.htaccess`.

> ```
> <Directory />
>     AllowOverride All
> </Directory>
> ```

Also, you should never set `AllowOverride All` for the root directory. The [Apache docs specifically warn against](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride) doing this:

> For security and performance reasons, do not set `AllowOverride` to anything other than None in your `<Directory "/">` block.

So, remove the `/var/www/staging/.htaccess` file and rework your vHost and `apache.conf` files something like the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName somewpsite.com
    ServerAlias somewpsite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/staging/some-wp-site
    <Directory /var/www/staging/some-wp-site>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All                
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**`apache.conf`**:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/staging>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "restricted area"
    AuthUserFile /var/www/staging/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

You probably also want to disable `MultiViews` (and `Indexes`) unless you are specifically using these. Otherwise, `MultiViews` will only probably end up conflicting with mod_rewrite at some point in your future.

Comment: Thanks MrWhite - Yes I noticed the issue with vhost overwritng apache.conf as well. I guess it leaves me no choice than to adjust every vhost in staging then. Thanks for the security fixup!